# Number of areas overlapped by exactly 3 circles

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry, computational-geometry

I have a task where i have any number of circles. All I know about one is its **centre and radius**. Now I need to find the number of areas which are overlapped by **exactly** 3 circles. I tried to solve it knowing that circles overlap when distance between their centres is shorter than sum of radiuses, but it got me nowhere.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a basic geometry, not a programming question.

Comment: By area, do you mean connected components? Would you be happy with a discrete approximation or do you need an exact result?

Comment: Are you asking for the count (number) of non-overlapping areas, or should each triple-bound region be counted as one despite overlaps, or something else? And is the *size* of each such region relevant?

Comment: @MarcusMüller: This could be a computational geometry problem, solved by code... if the question were more precise. So I would not close this question due to off-topic, but rather due to the question being unclear.

Answer (score 0):

A sweep-line algorithm should do the job.

Read about sweep-line algorithms in general [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm), about one particular (very important) algorithm [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bentley%E2%80%93Ottmann_algorithm). The overall structure of an algorithm for this problem would be similar to that of Bentley–Ottmann algorithm. Below are some details (not a full description but rather a sketch; a full description

Take all the leftmost (min X) and rightmost (max X) points on each circle. Sort all these points by their X coordinate. Put them to a priority queue.

Run a vertical sweep line along the X axis. The line contains a collection of Y coordinates of points where it intersects with the circles at the current X coordinate, sorted by Y.

Once the sweep line hits a leftmost circle point, add it to the the collection twice — once for the upper semicircle and once for the lower semicircle. Once the sweep line hits a rightmost circle point, remove the corresponding points from the collection. Keep track of the number of times each interval between two successive points is covered by circles. Keep track of identity of these areas. Whenever two points that belong to different circles appear next to each other, calculate their intersection points, and insert them to the point queue. Every time the sweep line hits an intersection point, swap the corresponding points in the collection and adjust area identities and overlap counts.

It's easy to visualise the algorithm by drawing some circles on a piece of paper, coloring each area differently, and slowly moving a ruler across the drawing, noting how it intersects with circles and areas.

Also google *"line sweep algorithm" "circles"*.